# How to install vkd3d on a specific prefix

Tags: linux, wine

I am trying to install vkd3d from https://github.com/HansKristian-Work/vkd3d-proton/releases/ using the installation file `setup_vkd3d_proton.sh` but it always installs in `/home/user/.wine`

How do I get it to install to another path?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could always, just make symlinks in the ~/.wine/ folder to your prefix..

I did this, by making the setup_vkd3d_proton.sh think my default wine folder is used, but instead it used my custom prefix through the symlinks..

Then you only need to have the symlinks during the vkd3d install, then delete them again, and restore your default wine prefix..

Remember to create symlinks for these folders/files in your wine custom prefix..

"dosdevices - Folder link"

"drive_c - Folder link"

".update-timestamp - File link"

"system.reg - File link"

"user.reg - File link"

"userdef.reg - File link"

"winetricks.log - File link"

Then it should install like normal but in your custom wine prefix..

Answer (score 0):

Set WINEPREFIX when running `setup_vkd3d_proton.sh`:

```
env WINEPREFIX='/my/custom/prefix' setup_vkd3d_proton.sh install
```